# How can I add the actual date automatically in Django Forms?

Tags: python, django, date, time, django-forms

Im new in Django, and Im trying to create a form for add books for my app. But I want the date of publication not included in the form. Instead I want the current system date is obtained and will " add" the form to save my model . How could I do this?

There is part of my **views.py**:

```
def add_book(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = BookForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_book = form.save(commit=False)
        new_book.publication_date = django_timezone
        new_book.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
    else:
        print form.errors
else:
    form = BookForm()
return render_to_response('add_book.html',{'form':form})
```

There is my **forms.py**:

```
class BookForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        exclude = ('publication_date',)
```

And my model **Book**:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
    publication_date = models.DateField()
    num_pages = models.IntegerField(blank = True, null = True)

    class Admin:
        list_display = ('title', 'publisher', 'publication_date')
        list_filter = ('publisher', 'publication_date')
        ordering = ('-publication_date',)
        search_fields = ('title',)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I used this **template** for form:

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
  {% block title %}Add a new Book{% endblock %}
  {% block content %}
    <h3> Here you can add a new book into the local DataBase </h3>
    <form action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}>
      <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ form.title.errors }}
        <label for="id_title">Book Title</label>
        {{ form.title }}
      </div>
      <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ form.authors.errors }}
        <label for="id_authors">Authores</label>
        {{ form.authors }}
      </div>
      <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ form.publisher.errors }}
        <label for="id_publisher">Publishers</label>
        {{ form.publisher }}
      </div>
      <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ form.num_pages.errors }}
        <label for="id_num_pages">Number of Pages</label>
        {{ form.num_pages }}
      </div>


      <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
    </form>
  {% endblock %}
```

I've temporarily disabled Django csrf because I do not need for my purpose

Answer (score 0):

**To do that, you need to pass the `default` argument as `timezone.now` in `publication_date` model field.**

**models.py**

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)

    # pass the default argument in publication_date field
    publication_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)

    num_pages = models.IntegerField(blank = True, null = True)

    class Admin:
        list_display = ('title', 'publisher', 'publication_date')
        list_filter = ('publisher', 'publication_date')
        ordering = ('-publication_date',)
        search_fields = ('title',)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**views.py**

After doing that, you can directly call `.save()` on modelform. Now, the book object will be created with the aware datetime.

```
def add_book(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BookForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_book = form.save() # directly save the book object
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
        else:
            print form.errors
    else:
        form = BookForm()
    return render_to_response('add_book.html',{'form':form})
```

**Why we did not use `auto_now_add` argument in the model field?**

From django's [`auto_now_add` documentation:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add)

Django's `auto_now_add` uses current time which is not timezone aware. So, it is better to explicitly specify default value using `default` argument.

> If you want to be able to modify this field, set `default=timezone.now`
>   (from django.utils.timezone.now()) instead of `auto_now_add=True`.